# How to prevent first route to show on notification click in react-native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-native-push-notification

I have implemented the push notification using `react-native-push-nofication` here is my push notification configuration.

```
const configure = () => {

 var _token

 PushNotification.configure({

   onRegister: function(token) {
     //process token

     //alert(JSON.stringify(token));
     Clipboard.setString(JSON.stringify(token))
   },

   onNotification: function(notification) {
     // process the notification
     // required on iOS only
     navigator.navigate(notification.data.url);
    // notification.finish(PushNotificationIOS.FetchResult.NoData);
   },

   senderID: Config.GCMSENDERKEY,

   permissions: {
     alert: true,
     badge: true,
     sound: true
   },

   popInitialNotification: true,
   requestPermissions: true,

 });
};
```

This code is navigating to the desire route successfully but when the application is in background, when user click on notification it shows the root route of the application (splash screen) before navigating to the desire route. I don't want splash screen to show up at all.

Answer (score 1):

I just reviewed the library and I have to say, it's really bad designed. You should move to [react-native-firebase](https://github.com/invertase/react-native-firebase).

But if you want to stay with it:

The first thing we have to figure out, is, how we can get the notification with which the app was opened?

We can't use `onNotification` from the Library, because we don't know when the callback will be called.

The library has a option `popInitialNotification` which will throw the initial notification with which the app was opened. If you search for this variable in the source code of the library you will [find the following](https://github.com/zo0r/react-native-push-notification/blob/82544256b63c5cb0793b590ce5d60a298f4ee658/index.js#L92):

```
    if ( this.hasPoppedInitialNotification === false &&
            ( options.popInitialNotification === undefined || options.popInitialNotification === true ) ) {
        this.popInitialNotification(function(firstNotification) {
            if ( firstNotification !== null ) {
                this._onNotification(firstNotification, true);
            }
        }.bind(this));
        this.hasPoppedInitialNotification = true;
    }
```

As you can see, it will call a [function](https://github.com/zo0r/react-native-push-notification/blob/82544256b63c5cb0793b590ce5d60a298f4ee658/index.js#L311) named `popInitialNotification(callback)` with a callback function with the initial notification.

You can now use the function to get the initial notification.

```
PushNotification.popInitialNotification(function(notification) {

});
```

With this you have now access to the initial notification directly, without to wait for `onNotification`.

From here on you can use SwitchNavigator from react-navigation like in the following example: https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/auth-flow.html

Comment: Where do i write this code inside `PushNotification.configure` or anywhere else in my code?

Comment: plus the library you mentioned `react-native-firebase` can i use this to get push notification on IOS and android both?

Comment: Outside of `PushNotification.configure`. Put it there where you display the splash screen.

Comment: Yes, with `react-native-firebase` you can use both platforms.

Comment: unfortunately it showing me the same behaviour.. my problem is not getting the notification object.. my problem was that it showing the root screen of stack before navigating i don't want that i want to directly navigate to the desire screen

Comment: Yes, I know. But for your described behaviour you need access to the notification to check if there is a notification, THEN you can handle if you show the splashscreen or not.

Comment: There is no option like "showSplashscreenOnlyWithoutNotification". You need to handle it on your own.

Comment: Exactly that was my question how can i handle that .. your solution doesn't get me anywhere

Comment: I don't give you a solution. I just give you a way how to do it on your own. If you want a solution, pay someone for it.

Comment: whatever you doesn't help. thanks anyway there no point in arguing